# How do i add userextension js file to Selenium IDE 3.4.4

Tags: javascript, selenium, ide

Older versions of Selenium IDE allowed users to add a .js file to the "Selenium Core extensions (user-extensions.js)" field on the "General" tab of the "Selenium IDE Options" dialog. Selenium IDE 3.4.4 doesn't display an Options menu. I've tried Alt+O and Ctrl+O and neither one displays the menu. How would I go about getting my custom extensions to appear in the Command drop down of 
Selenium IDE 3.4.4?